# Google Play Services not imported correctly

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I know. Many similar questions. I have not found any answer that solves this one.
How do I get the Google Play Services lib to work in Eclipse 3.7.1 with Android SDK Tools 23.0.2?

Tried alot of combinations. First, to get the lib to import correctly. I've tried these methods beside the obvious flawed from Google. (I've also removed the write-protection from all files)

1. Copy the code to the workspace and use File --> import --> Android --> Used ex... then checked the COPY-box.
2. Copy the folder to another place and then import into the workspace and linking it.

Then in my project I added the meta-data-thing into my  in androidmanifest.xml.

In my project I've clicked Properties --> Android --> In the lower panel I've added the Google Services Project that I've imported.

Now everything builds. (I've seen that many people have trouble with that.)

In properties, under the option Java Build Path the libraries are checked under the tab "Order and export".

The method I use in my main activity is

```
   GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailabl(..)...
```

When I run the application I get an exception, `NoClassDefFoundError.`

And for sure, the class is not in the APK. I've checked, but some other classes under from gms.internal exists?!

In my project under Android dependencies is the 1k output from the imported lib. Under Android private libraries is the full jar.

**Update**: Solved this by downloading the latest version of [http://www.eclipse.org](http://www.eclipse.org/). (The update function didn't find anything).